# Display a list in React Native using Meteor

Tags: meteor, react-native

I have a RN app +Meteor App as a backend.

The publishing is set up in Meteor>server>publications:

```
    Meteor.publish('deputies', () => {
    return Deputies.find({});
    });
```

The Subscription is set up in RN> DeputiesList

```
class Deputies_List extends Component{

  render(){
    const {deputies}= this.props;

    return(
      <View>
          {this.props.deputies.map(deputy=><DeputyDetail deputy={deputy} key={deputy._id}/>)}
      </View>
      );
  }
}


export default createContainer(params=>{
  return{
    deputies: Meteor.collection('deputies').find({}),
  };

},Deputies_List)
```

Here is the DeputyDetail component:

```
const DeputyDetail =({deputy})=>{

  const{name} = deputy;

  return(
    <Text>Nom : {name}</Text>
    );

}


export default DeputyDetail;
```

Error: no message, but nothing appears on the screen. 
I should have one entry.

Any idea ?

Comment: Change this const DeputyDetail =({deputy})=>{

  const{name} = deputy; to this const DeputyDetail =({name})=>{

Answer (score 0):

From your code, it doesn't appear that you are subscribing to the `deputies` publication. I think if you call `Meteor.subscribe('deputies')` within `createContainer` you should see your expected data.

Comment: I added Meteor.subscribe like so, but no difference

    export default createContainer(params=>{
    Meteor.subscribe('deputies');
    return{
    deputies: Meteor.collection('deputies').find({}),
   };
    },Deputies_List)